# wpf application runs in debug mode but doesn't run without debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

My WPF application successfully runs in VS2015 in debug mode. However when starting without debugging application starts and immediately finishes. The same happens when starting exe file from the Debug/Release folder.
Event Viewer shows the following .Net Runtime Error:

> Application: Cisco.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.InvalidOperationException at
>   MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.CheckReadOnly(System.Object,
>   System.Object) at
>   MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(Int32, System.Object,
>   System.Object) at
>   MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32,
>   System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.AttachDataItem() at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean)
>   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine+Task.Run(Boolean) at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32,
>   IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,
>   System.String, System.String, Int32) at
>   System.Windows.MessageBox.ShowCore(IntPtr, System.String,
>   System.String, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton,
>   System.Windows.MessageBoxImage, System.Windows.MessageBoxResult,
>   System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions) at
>   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(System.String) at
>   Cisco.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs) at
>   System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32,
>   IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window) at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window) at
>   Cisco.App.Main()

I know that there are many questions with the same problem, but no solution has fixed my problem yet.

During run MainWindow even doesn't appear. So I moved all OnStartup method to the try catch block trying to identify this exception with the MessageBox but MessageBox doesn't appear too.

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }


    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            Ioc.Setup();

            Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow();

            Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I've uploaded the full [solution](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16USjjKwxsQsmOOhacY2uilwfXWkBZVOx) to the google drive. Maybe it would be more useful.

Comment: Without code, it is very hard to say what the problem is. Try commenting out code around where it happens to try to locate the issue. It seems related to either a MessageBox (or do you have one in a catch block?) or a Binding.

Comment: Before I run your solution. Does your app write/delete to the system's files? Is it save to run it on my machine? Please, be sure and clear in your answer!

Comment: No worries about that. This project is completely safe for your pc. It doesn't make any changes in any system files or registry entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've found the cause.
The problem was related to the twoWay binding to a public variable with a private setter. After making this setter public application runs successfully.