# Why does the exe not execute?

Tags: c#, wpf, exe, datacontext

half a day that I try to figure out why the exe file generated by VS doesn't start. Hope I can find help! So it is a c# wpf prism App, and it works just fine when started from VS. The exe file however doesn't execute. Checking the EventViewer, it tells that the KERNELBASE.dll faults. I googled this, found many posts, but no solution that works for me. The VS solution is made out of 4 projects, the startup one has referencies to all assemblies needed by under-projects.
I could localise the line of code that makes problem:
In a UserControl I have this:

```
    <catSelector:CatiaSelectorView
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="2.5,2.5,0,2.5"
        DataContext="{Binding SketchSelector}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsCatiaConnected}" />
```

Having this, the app works fine from VS but not from the exe.
If I remove the DataContext Property setting:

```
    <catSelector:CatiaSelectorView
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="2.5,2.5,0,2.5"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsCatiaConnected}" />
```

the exe works!
But obviously the control's function is lost. The catSelector namespace is in the same assembly as the consumer. I have no clue what happens here, thanks for support.

Added 26.04:

[In the EventViewer there is .NET runtime error too:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sQkq.png)

Comment: Any error message when it doesn't work? Be sure to check the event log for crash reports.

Comment: Hi, by event log you mean the windows "Event viewer"? Yes i checked it, it shows the KERNELBASE.dll fault as mentionned.

Comment: That's all? That's unusual. Normally, if an application crashes without a message, you have an error with source ".NET Runtime" in the "Application" log.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: I have windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I googled after the .NET Runtime error and found that post:
[wpf application runs in debug mode but doesn't run without debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680829/wpf-application-runs-in-debug-mode-but-doesnt-run-without-debugging)

Same problem at my end: twoWay binding to a public variable with private setter. I am however pretty sure I already made this common mistake and got somehow a more explicit error from VS.
Anyway. Thank you for support (PMF leading me to the .net runtime error eventualy made the difference).